# In React, how to use one method to toggle states for multiple checkboxes values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 _toggleValue: function(state) {
    //?? how to do it 
    //this.setState(???);
  },

render() {
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={this._toggleValue.bind(null, this.state.a)} />
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={this._toggleValue.bind(null, this.state.b)} />
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={this._toggleValue.bind(null, this.state.c)} />
    </form>
  </div>
}
```

There are quite lot checkboxes in the form, currently, what I am doing is to define one method for each checkbox. How can I define one method which can be used by all the checkboxes.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [LinkedStateMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

Your checkboxes would look something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' checkedLink={this.linkState('a')}/>
<input type='checkbox' checkedLink={this.linkState('b')}/>
<input type='checkbox' checkedLink={this.linkState('c')}/>
```

This will automatically keep the values of the checkboxes `a`, `b` and `c` up to date with the state variables.

Comment: The LinkedStateMixin is obsolete, you should use checked, defaultChecked and onChange to achieve the same goal. Sending parameters is the way to go as in the next answer by @aarkeio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `id` on your checkboxes and retrieve it from `event.target.id` that is passed to `onChange` handler as below:

```
_toggleValue: function(event) {
    var state = this.state[event.target.id];
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" id={1} onChange={this._toggleValue}/>
                <input type="checkbox" id={2} onChange={this._toggleValue}/>
                <input type="checkbox" id={3} onChange={this._toggleValue}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I like it to use event.target get ref for the element. However, how can I change the state by using method "setState" here, since object field is dynamic value.

Comment: You could do that actually: `var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state); newState[event.target.id] = checkboxState; this.setState(newState);`

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
toggleCheckbox(name, event) {
  let change = !this.state[name];
  this.setState({name: change});
}

<input type="checkbox" name="active" defaultChecked={this.state.active} onChange={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this, 'active')} />       
<input type="checkbox" name="shared" defaultChecked={this.state.shared} onChange={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this, 'shared')} />
```

Note the "defaultChecked" and that I'm not using the preventDefault() statement.